# process a collection of urls in parallel and return an IEnumerable

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, web-scraping, system.reactive

I have a collection of urls for scraping and I want to download resources in parallel, while returning a collection of strongly typed results.

Having a `WebClient.DownloadString()`  and a "`MyTypedResult Process(string s)`"

How do I wrap it up to have a `string[] urls =>   IEnumerable<MyTypedResult>` conversion?

```
string[] urls = {"url1","url2","url3"};
List<MyTypedResult> ResultCollection = new List<MyTypedResult>();
foreach (var u in urls)
{
    WebClient wc = new WebClient();
    var content = wc.DownloadString(u);
    MyTypedResult r = Process(content);
    ResultCollection.Add(r);
}
```

I want web requests to run in parallel, but I need a resulting collection in a List;

Comment: It's not really clear what you are asking. Please show some more code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the new toy `HttpClient` from .NET 4.5 to get the result in parallel:

```
var httpClient = new HttpClient();

var tasks = urls.Select(url => httpClient.GetStringAsync(url)
                        .ContinueWith(task =>
                        {
                            string response = task.Result;
                            return ConvertToStrongType(response);
                        }));

 Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
 var results = tasks.Select(t => t.Result);
```

Comment: wow, that looks prety simple. I'll give it a shot and see where it'll get me.

Comment: Now if there is a way to run those downloads in parallel?

Comment: @Alexander Taran: Yes of course, using GetStringAsync take the code work in parallel

Comment: Well, looking at the requests in fiddler they are definitly occuring one after another.

Comment: @AlexanderTaran: of course you see in the filder one after another, but the code from server use Tasks process url, it does nearly mean each thread for each request. Image: sending the first reuquest, the code does not wait response return to process, it continue to send the second request, it this parallel like you mean, right?

Comment: if that was the case, then there would be at least two requests pending at the same time, but next request starts only when the previous one is finished.

Comment: @AlexanderTaran: I am afraid I don't understand why two request pneding at the same time. But you can check the code by running this, put Thread.Sleep(5000) to see what happens

Comment: Yeah, I did. And it does wait for 5 seconds between requests. Not executing them in parallel to each other.

Comment: @AlexanderTaran: take a look timestamp in Fiddler,  does the second request come after first in 5s?

Comment: before return ConvertToStrongType

Comment: @AlexanderTaran: you are correct, I changed the answer, pls check again

Comment: @CuongLe is there any way to limit the # of tasks running in parallel?

Answer (score 2):

This is Rx version with `HttpClient`:

```
var urls = new[] { "url1", "url2", "url3" };
var client = new HttpClient();
var results = from url in urls.ToObservable()
              from content in client.GetStringAsync(url).ToObservable()
              select Process(content);
var enumerable = results.ToEnumerable();
```

Answer (score 1):

Following is the code, it uses Parallel.ForEach for parallel downloading contents from url.
You need to use ConcurrentList to ensure that collection should be populated in parallel without having thread locking issue.

```
void YourTask()
{
    string[] urls = {"url1","url2","url3"};
    ConcurrentList<MyTypedResult> ResultCollection = new ConcurrentList<MyTypedResult>();

    Parallel.ForEach(urls, url => 
    {
        GetData(url);
        ResultCollection.TryAdd(myTypedResult);
    );

    //on this line all parallel task will be completed and ResultCollection will be filled with the results

}

MyTypedResult GetData(string url)
{
   WebClient wc = new WebClient();
    var content = wc.DownloadString(url);
    MyTypedResult r = Process(content);
    return r;
}
```